# How to fetch elements from a joint table with manytomany relation

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entities, I linked them with a manytomany relation creating a joint table filled with the entities id.
I want to findall with the id from the joint table but i have no idea how to do that.

**The first entity which reprensent the projects **

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "project")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProjectEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int Project_id;


    private String  name;


    private String about;

    private String link_image;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "project_skill",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Project_id", referencedColumnName = "Project_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Skill_id", referencedColumnName = "Skill_id"))
    private Set<SkillEntity> skills = new HashSet<>();

}
```

**The second entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "skills")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SkillEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int Skill_id;

    private String  name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "skills")
    private Set<ProjectEntity> assignedProjects = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**Their repos :**

```
public interface ProjectRepo extends JpaRepository<ProjectEntity, Integer> {


}


public interface SkillRepository extends JpaRepository<SkillEntity, Integer> {


}
```

**I made this service which works I got all the projects but I have no idea what to put in the skillService
**

```
@Service
public class ProjectService {
    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepo projectRepo;

    public ProjectEntity saveDetails(ProjectEntity projectEntity) {
        return projectRepo.save(projectEntity);
    }

    public List<ProjectEntity> getAllProjects() {
        return projectRepo.findAll();
    }


}
```

**and finally the ProjectController (I have a Skill controller but there's nothing in it)
**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class ProjectController {
    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @PostMapping("/addProject")
    public ProjectEntity postDetails(@RequestBody ProjectEntity project){
        return projectService.saveDetails(project);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getProjects")
    public List<ProjectEntity> getProjects(){

        return projectService.getAllProjects();
    }





}
```

there are only two skills, dev and design ( the projects can be in both categories) and I want to list project from a certain skill.

Thanks